# Recieving File with Socket in Android

Tags: android, sockets, android-studio

I want to transfer a file between server and client, Server is a Windows program written in Delphi with Indy and Client is an Android

this is my client code for reading from socket :

```
...
InputStream IS = S.getInputStream();
byte[] FBytes = new byte[FileSize];
FileOutputStream FOS = new FileOutputStream(TempFile);
BufferedOutputStream BOS = new BufferedOutputStream(FOS);
int BytesRead = IS.read(FBytes);
int CurrProgress = BytesRead;
do {
    Log.d("DOWNLOAD", "BytesRead2 = " + Integer.toString(BytesRead));
    if(CurrProgress < FBytes.length) {
        Log.d("DOWNLOAD", "prog < BytesRead" );
        BytesRead = IS.read(FBytes);
        if (BytesRead > 0)
          CurrProgress += BytesRead;
        B.clear();
        B.putInt("ProgValue", CurrProgress);
        Msg.what = MSG_FILE_PROGRESS;
        Hdlr.dispatchMessage(Msg);
        Log.d("DOWNLOAD", "BytesRead = " + Integer.toString(BytesRead));
    }
} while (BytesRead > 0);
Log.d(TAG, "Download Loop Finished");
```

File will download but the problem is size of downloaded file is lower than original file and the socket read command stay on last read. in other words file has been downloaded but CurrProgress is lower than FBytes.length so while loop execute onetime more and program hangs on read command because there is no more data sent from server

I have been tested server with an windows program and there is no problem in the server code

I have tested many ways like this but no chance :

```
int BytesRead = IS.read(FBytes, 0, FBytes.length);
int CurrProgress = BytesRead;
do {
    Log.d("DOWNLOAD", "BytesRead2 = " + Integer.toString(BytesRead));
    if(CurrProgress < FBytes.length) {
        Log.d("DOWNLOAD", "prog < BytesRead" );
        BytesRead = IS.read(FBytes, CurrProgress, (FBytes.length - CurrProgress));
    ...
```

- FileSize value is correct and came from server as a string value before reading file bytes

What goes wrong ?!, thanks ...

Edit :

Complete code do many other jobs but code of reading file is like this :

```
public void Run()
    {
        Running = true;

        try{
            try{
                InetAddress ServerAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                S = new Socket(ServerAddr, SERVER_PORT);
                Log.d(TAG, "Connecting ...");
                Out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(S.getOutputStream())), true);
                In  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(S.getInputStream()));
                switch (Job) {
                    ...
                    }
                    case GetFile: {
                        this.SendMessage(Cmd);
                        response = In.readLine();
                        if(response.equals("1"))
                        {
                            Hdlr.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_SERVER_ACCEPT);

                            response = In.readLine();
                            int FileSize = Integer.parseInt(response);

                            if (context.getFilesDir().getFreeSpace() < 3 * FileSize)
                            {
                                Hdlr.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_ERROR_FREESPACE);

                                Log.d(TAG, "There is no Free Space !");
                            }
                            else {

                                final Message Msg = new Message();
                                final Bundle B = new Bundle();
                                B.putInt("FSize", FileSize);
                                Msg.what = MSG_FILE_SIZE;
                                Msg.setData(B);
                                Hdlr.dispatchMessage(Msg);

                                try {
                                    File TempDir, TempFile, MainDir, MainFile;

                                    switch(FileType)
                                    {
                                        case 2 :
                                            TempDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "TempMP3");
                                            if(!TempDir.exists()) {
                                                TempDir.mkdir();
                                            }
                                            TempFile = new File(TempDir, Integer.toString(FileIndex) + ".mp3");
                                            if(TempFile.exists()) {
                                                TempFile.delete();
                                            }
                                            break;
                                        default :
                                            TempDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "TempLevel");
                                            if(!TempDir.exists()) {
                                                TempDir.mkdir();
                                            }
                                            TempFile = new File(TempDir, Integer.toString(FileIndex) + ".zip");
                                            if(TempFile.exists()) {
                                                TempFile.delete();
                                            }
                                    }

                                    InputStream IS = S.getInputStream();
                                    byte[] FBytes = new byte[4096];

                                    FileOutputStream FOS = new FileOutputStream(TempFile);
                                    BufferedOutputStream BOS = new BufferedOutputStream(FOS);
                                    int BytesRead = 0;
                                    int CurrProgress = 0;

                                    do {
                                        Log.d("DOWNLOAD", "prog < BytesRead" );
                                        BytesRead = IS.read(FBytes, 0, FBytes.length);
                                        BOS.write(FBytes, 0, BytesRead);

                                        if (BytesRead > 0)
                                            CurrProgress += BytesRead;

                                        B.clear();
                                        B.putInt("ProgValue", CurrProgress);
                                        Msg.what = MSG_FILE_PROGRESS;
                                        Hdlr.dispatchMessage(Msg);

                                        Log.d("DOWNLOAD", "BytesRead = " + Integer.toString(BytesRead));
                                    } while (CurrProgress < FileSize);

                                    Log.d(TAG, "Download Loop Finished");
                                    if (CurrProgress != FBytes.length) {
                                        BOS.close();

                                        Hdlr.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_ERROR_FILESIZE);
                                        Log.d(TAG, "File Size Problem");
                                    } else {
                                        BOS.close();
                                        Log.d(TAG, "File Downloaded successfully, Preparing to Unzip ... ");
                                        try {

                                            MainDir = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "Levels");
                                            if(!MainDir.exists())
                                            {
                                                MainDir.mkdir();
                                            }

                                            File LevelDir = new File(MainDir, Integer.toString(FileIndex));
                                            if(!LevelDir.exists())
                                            {
                                                LevelDir.mkdir();
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                LevelDir.delete();
                                            }

                                            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(TempFile);
                                            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
                                            ZipEntry ze = null;
                                            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                                                MainFile = new File(LevelDir, ze.getName());
                                                FileOutputStream FOut = new FileOutputStream(MainFile);
                                                for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {
                                                    FOut.write(c);
                                                }

                                                zin.closeEntry();
                                                FOut.close();
                                            }
                                            zin.close();
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "Unzip Error : ", e);
                                        }
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception E) {
                                    Err = 1;
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Get File Error : ", E);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (Listener != null)
                            {
                                Listener.callbackMessageReceiver(response);

                                Hdlr.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_ERROR_SERVER);
                            }
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    ...
                }

            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                Hdlr.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_ERROR_SEND);
                Log.d(TAG, "Connect Error : ", e);
            }
            finally{
                if(Out != null) {
                    Out.flush();
                    Out.close();
                }
                if(In != null)
                {
                    In.close();
                }

                S.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "Err Value is : " + Integer.toString(Err));
                if(Err == 0)
                {
                    Hdlr.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_SUCCESS);
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "Sending Ends");
            }
        }catch (Exception E){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error : ", E);

        }
    }
```

CurrProgress is lower than FileSize ( the difference is about 4 or 5 KB ) and the while loop hangs on read command !

Comment: Yes i see. Please tell us the file sizes and exactly how many bytes missing.

Comment: `if(CurrProgress < FBytes.length) ` That should be ` if(CurrProgress < FileSize)`

Comment: You have a read before the loop. Not nice. Do all the reads in the loop.

Comment: `while (BytesRead > 0);` That should be: `while (CurrendProgress < FileSize );`

Comment: ` BytesRead = IS.read(FBytes, CurrProgress, (FBytes.length - CurrProgress));` Better: ` BytesRead = IS.read(FBytes, CurrProgress, (FileSize - CurrProgress));`

Comment: `int BytesRead; int CurrProgress` Please adapt to the java convention to start variable names lower case. `int bytesRead; int currProgress`. Now your code is difficult to read.

Comment: @greenapps thanks but length is same as FileSize, I have tried this ways but the problem exists , for example FileSize is "1330858" bytes but CurrProgress stay on "1326703" bytes and the loop hangs on read command

Comment: Which read command? You should never ask more bytes to read then FileSize-CurrentProgress. And why did you not tell the size of the missing chunk? Do i have to calculate it?

Comment: Please show the code for determining `FileSize` too. Put it in your code. Not in a comment.

Comment: Have you checked if the first bytes of the file are equal to the ones sent?

Comment: There is only one read command in while loop !. File size is correct and is exactly the size of original file, the difference is 4155 bytes

Comment: You have also one read command BEFORE the loop! Thats what i said.

Comment: `byte[] FBytes = new byte[FileSize];`. It is not a good idea to declare a buffer that can hold the whole file. Better use a small buffer of 4096 and in the loop read chuncks and immediately write them to the file output stream. Then you can download files of any size. MB's GB's.

Comment: `File size is correct and is exactly the size of original file,` I do believe that. But show how you determined it as i think that the culprit is there.

Comment: `response = In.readLine();`. That is the culprit indeed. You used an `In`. And after that `InputStream IS = S.getInputStream();`. So you will have twice `S.getInputStream()`. Impossible.  But show complete code. Starting from defining `In`. Put it in your main code. Not in a separate block.

Comment: That is much to much code suddenly. So you have indeed twice an S.getInputStream(). The first one with a BufferedInputReader. This reader will just read much more than one line. And all but the line is unused and dumped. So do away with `In`. Use only `IS`. IS has no readLine() but you can easily make your own.

Comment: @greenapps thanks, the problem solved, I have posted it as an answer

Comment: That is not the way it usually goes here. You should not have posted that as an answer as the answer had been given by me in a comment already. Instead you should have invited me to post my comment as an answer as i solved your problem.

Comment: @greenapps , thanks for your help but the problem and the answer was another things and if you read the answer you can see it

Comment: No. `What goes wrong ?!, thanks ..`. So i told you. And i even told you how you could repair it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I will post it as answer, it may be useful

The problem was that server sends File immediately after sending FileSize and I think the BufferedReader gets some bytes of File so the size of bytes given by IS are lower than FileSize, example of Server :

```
...
WriteLn(FileSize);
Write(FileStream);
...
```

Now, Server first sends FileSize then wait for a response from client, after checking freespace in client it sends a Ready response to server and then Server sends the File Stream, for example :

```
...
WriteLn(FileSize);
Response := ReadLn();
if Response = "READY" then
 Write(FileStream);
...
```

and codes in client are like this :

```
...
BufferedInputStream BIS = new BufferedInputStream(S.getInputStream());
In  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(S.getInputStream()));
...
response = In.readLine();
int FileSize = Integer.parseInt(response);
if (context.getFilesDir().getFreeSpace() < 3 * FileSize)
{
    Hdlr.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_ERROR_FREESPACE);
    Log.d(TAG, "There is no Free Space !");

    this.SendMessage("NOT_READY");
}
else {
    ...
    try {
        this.SendMessage("READY");

        byte[] FBytes = new byte[8192];
        FileOutputStream FOS = new FileOutputStream(TempFile);
        BufferedOutputStream BOS = new BufferedOutputStream(FOS);
        int BytesRead = 0;
        int CurrProgress = 0;
        while (CurrProgress < FileSize){
            Log.d("DOWNLOAD", "Available : " + Integer.toString(BIS.availabl
            BytesRead = BIS.read(FBytes, 0, FBytes.length);
            BOS.write(FBytes, 0, BytesRead);
            if (BytesRead > 0)
                CurrProgress += BytesRead;
            B.clear();
            B.putInt("ProgValue", CurrProgress);
            Msg.what = MSG_FILE_PROGRESS;
            Hdlr.dispatchMessage(Msg);
            Log.d("DOWNLOAD", "BytesRead = " + Integer.toString(BytesRead));
        }
```

There is no problem and everything works fine